# Making a Template in Orchard for a Projection of a custom ContentType (NivoSlider)

Tags: orchardcms, nivo-slider

I have a site theme I'm trying to import into [Orchard 1.4.2](http://www.orchardproject.net/) and I only have a few areas left. One of them is a [NivoSlider](http://nivo.dev7studios.com/) implemented on the homepage of this theme. Now I decided rather than forcing the maintainer of the site to know the proper HTML and format required to get this working that I would create a new content type representing a single slide, add a Projection Widget to the Featured Zone and create a custom template to structure the HTML correctly for the slider to work, but I'm running into a snag, the format for the Nivo Slider required all of the images first in a DIV and then a series of other DIVs representing the caption associated with each slide.

```
<div id="slider-container-default">
    <div id="slider-frame"><div id="slider-box"></div></div>
    <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
        <img src='images/slider/slide1.jpg' alt='' title='#htmlcaption1' />
        <img src='images/slider/slide2.jpg' alt='' title='#htmlcaption2' />
        <img src='images/slider/slide3.jpg' alt='' title='#htmlcaption3' />
    </div>
    <div id="htmlcaption1" class="nivo-html-caption">
        <h1>First Caption Title</h1>
        <p>Maecenas euismod, metus ac fermentum aliquam, diam turpis ornare odio, nec lacinia orci lectus eget odio. Cras at nulla mauris, at dignissim massa. Cras non est ac ligula lacinia varius sed quis augue.</p><a href="#" class="button medium">Read More &rarr;</a>
    </div>
    <div id="htmlcaption2" class="nivo-html-caption">
            <h1>Second Caption Title</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse vel lectus eu lacus interdum laoreet at a est. Pellentesque aliquam luctus dolor.</p><a href="#" class="button medium">Read More &rarr;</a>
    </div>
    <div id="htmlcaption3" class="nivo-html-caption">
        <h1>ThirdCaption Title</h1>
        <p>Pellentesque volutpat tempor imperdiet. Duis sit amet purus vel est auctor dignissim in sed tortor. Integer vitae ante non libero euismod iaculis.</p><a href="#" class="button medium">Read More &rarr;</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now, I have an Alternate that I'm trying to use to achieve this layout but I can't for the life of me figure out a way to get the alternate to behave in such a way as to do this. I tried using an alternate on the collection itself and just enumerate over the collection twice, one for the pictures and one for the captions, but I can't seem to figure out how to access the information on my slides in the template. I don't think I can do it at the item level because while I could have a custom template for the captions or the images, I don't know how to do it both both. Can I call `@Html.Display(Model.List)` in the collection template twice and provide a different item template for each call?

Comment: Kinda sounds like a widget would be a better choice over projections.  That would give you full control of the shape data and the template.  You could still use the content type you created for the client.

Comment: It actually is a Widget, It's the Projection Widget using a Query. But I'm still not sure how to go about it. I seem to have hit this wall trying to figure out how to access Part values or Field values.

Comment: I was trying to suggest building your own widget.  That gives you easy access to all the part and field values.  Projections are nice for a lot of scenarios, but if you need more control, maybe building your own widget is in order.

Comment: Ahh I see what you mean, sorry about that. I'm going to take a look online and see what I can find for tutorials to creating your own widget, do you know of a a good starting place? If I recall, It starts with using the codegen module to create the project for the widget, is that right?

Comment: I learned the most by looking through code.  Maybe have a look at the Blogs module.  There is a BlogArchivesPart that's used as a widget.  The documentation also has a simple start:  http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Writing-a-widget

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am currently designing a site that I included the Nivo slider into the Featured zone. I added an HTML widget into the HomePage layer, copy/pasted the Nivo HMTL code (from their website) into the widget's HTML editor, included the Nivo CSS and Javascript into the head of the home page (layout.cshtml), and added a separate window.load script at the bottom to initialize it with the options I wanted (duration, transistion effects, control navigation etc.). Once satisfied it was working, I also included the Nivo default theme CSS in the head.

The problem I spent the most time on was finding the correct path to the images. After finding a similar post here on SO, I wrote the full path (Themes/YourThemeName/Content/Images/image.xxx). That sorted it all out and it works flawlessly.

There is a [video on their site](http://nivo.dev7studios.com/support/jquery-plugin-usage/) that goes through the process of adding the slider to a normal HTML site. Hope this helps.